# LaTeX beamer animate package error

Tags: beamer, errors, packages, animate

I am trying to make a beamer with LaTeX and when I include the `\usepackage{animate}` it gives me this error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `pdfbase.sty' not
>   found.

May you please assist?

Thanks!

Comment: `pdfbase.sty` is part of [`media9`](https://ctan.org/pkg/media9). You should install it using the package manager of your TeX distribution.

Comment: Now it is telling me ! LaTeX Error: File `ocgbase.sty' not found. I have installed all the ocg related packages

Comment: `ocgbase.sty` is part of `ocgx2`. If you have more such problems you should either learn how to find the distribution package that contains a file (e.g. the MiKTeX package manager can do this for your) or do a full install of your TeX distribution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a very individual problem due to an outdated TeX installation.

Answer (score 3):

OK sorted. Updated the whole MiKTeX and LaTeX installations. It appears that my packages where obsolete.

Thanks for your assistance!